# How to log kvm/qemu guest boot/reboot/shutdown time?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, logging, kvm-virtualization

I manage an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server running several guest VMs through KVM/qemu, and I'm asked to log boot, reboot and shutdown times of guests.

Is there a way to catch this kind of events for example in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: Have you tried /var/log/libvirt/libvirtd.log ?

Comment: @AndrewDomaszek Thank for your comment, you put me on the right path: on my system `libvirtd.log` wasn't helpful, but files in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/` were. I added an answer to help others passing by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that such events are already logged for each VM in a file named in a way similar to `vmname.log`, located in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/`.

So one can get boot and shutdown times using a command like this:

```
$ sudo grep -e 'starting up' -e 'shutting down' /var/log/libvirt/qemu/vmname-log
```

Still can't find a way to get reboot time without looking at guest log files.